# What is the role of mixins in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less-mixins, gutter

I am a beginner in bootstrap and I'm not able to understand this concept.

What's the meaning of the `less` code below?

```
// Creates  wrapper for a series of columns

.make-row(@gutter: @grid-gutter-width) {

  // Then clear the floated columns
  .clearfix();

  @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    margin-left:  (@gutter / -2);
    margin-right: (@gutter / -2);
  }

  // Negative margin nested rows out to align the content of columns
  .row {
    margin-left:  (@gutter / -2);
    margin-right: (@gutter / -2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you already tried compile usage this mixin into css? I think it is self-explanatory. Mixins could be treated like simple functions (with parameters or without).

[Look at the compiled code.](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%2F%2F%20Temporary%20variable%20for%20example%5Cn%40screen-sm-min%3A%201000px%3B%5Cn%5Cn%2F%2F%20Clearfix%20definition%5Cn.clearfix()%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%26%3A%3Aafter%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20content%3A%20%5C%22%5C%22%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20display%3A%20table%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20clear%3A%20both%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%2F%2F%20Creates%20%20wrapper%20for%20a%20series%20of%20columns%5Cn.make-row(%40gutter%3A%20%40grid-gutter-width)%20%7B%5Cn%5Cn%20%20%2F%2F%20Then%20clear%20the%20floated%20columns%5Cn%20%20.clearfix()%3B%5Cn%5Cn%20%20%40media%20(min-width%3A%20%40screen-sm-min)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20margin-left%3A%20%20(%40gutter%20%2F%20-2)%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20margin-right%3A%20(%40gutter%20%2F%20-2)%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%5Cn%20%20%2F%2F%20Negative%20margin%20nested%20rows%20out%20to%20align%20the%20content%20of%20columns%5Cn%20%20.row%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20margin-left%3A%20%20(%40gutter%20%2F%20-2)%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20margin-right%3A%20(%40gutter%20%2F%20-2)%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.my-row%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct.make-row(%40gutter%3A%2030px)%3B%5Cn%7D%22%7D)